# The Client Certificate provided could not be cloned because it is not exportable

Tags: c#, azure-keyvault

Retrieving a secret from KeyVault and trying to clone the certificate to pass in a HTTP call gives the exception error bellow.

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(secretValue));
var clonedCert = new X509Certificate2(cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx));
```

**Exception:**

The Client Certificate provided could not be cloned because it is not exportable. Make sure that you pass the X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable flag when creating the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity:
To date when creating a KeyVault in Azure by default the certificates policy will allow the private keys to be exported.

As dumb is it may sound the error also says: `Make sure that you pass the X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable flag when creating the certificate.`

To solve it, if you dont have a password to your secret, use:

```
new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(secret), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```